# Shell-Removing File Extensions through Args

Tags: shell

I wish to remove the file extensions in a folder by getting the extension type as argument.

Below is my code and it is not working as i expected.

```
if [ $# -ne 1 ]
then
    echo -e "\nUsage: $0 Ext"
    echo -e "\nExt - Refers to the extension you want to remove"
    echo -e "\nExample1: $0 .txt\nExample2: $0 .doc\nExample3: $0 .pdf\n"
exit 1
fi

ext=$1

for i in *$ext
do
    echo $i
    filename=${i%\$ext}
    echo $i
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost correct, but you need to remove the escape and echo the filename. Code below also shows the use of basename:

```
for i in *$ext
do
    echo $i
    filename1=${i%$ext}
    filename2=$(basename $i $ext)
    echo $filename1
    echo $filename2
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace extension using this script

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -ne 1 ]
then
    echo -e "\nUsage: $0 Ext"
    echo -e "\nExt - Refers to the extension you want to remove"
    echo -e "\nExample1: $0 .txt\nExample2: $0 .doc\nExample3: $0 .pdf\n"
exit 1
fi

ext=$1

for i in *$ext
do
    echo $i
    new_name=`echo $i | sed 's/.'$ext'//g'`
    echo $new_name
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code :

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -ne 1 ]

then

    echo -e "\nUsage: $0 Ext"
    echo -e "\nExt - Refers to the extension you want to remove"
    echo -e "\nExample1: $0 .txt\nExample2: $0 .doc\nExample3: $0 .pdf\n"

exit 1
fi

ext=$1

for i in *$ext
do    
    echo $i

    new_name=`echo $i |rev|cut -d'.' -f2-|rev

    echo $new_name
done
```